# List of objects to Dictionary with distinct keys and selected values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `List` of objects of following class:

```
class Entry
{
    public ulong ID {get; set;}
    public DateTime Time {get; set;}
}
```

The list contains several object per ID value, each with different DateTime.

Can I use Linq to convert this `List<Entry>` to a `Dictionary<ulong, DateTime>` where the key is the ID and the value is `Min<DateTime>()` of the DateTimes of that ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you want to group by ID and *then* convert to a dictionary, so that you end up with one dictionary entry per ID:

```
var dictionary = entries.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                      // Find the earliest time for each group
                                      g => g.Min(x => x.Time));
```

Or:

```
                         // Group by ID, with each value being the time
var dictionary = entries.GroupBy(x => x.ID, x => x.Time)
                         // Find the earliest value in each group
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Min())
```

Comment: I think you scared away all the other answers as I'm sure there were at least two of them just a moment ago.

Comment: @vipirtti: Yup, there are two deleted answers, although one is less efficient and the other wouldn't work yet.